# SDL 2013 SP1 - XML Error prevents successful save of new component

Tags: cme, content-manager, schema, keyword

**The Problem** is this, we’ve created a schema at a high level (020) in the blueprint called “link.” We’ve also created a category called “URI Classification” in the same publication, but have not defined any keywords.  We’ve then used the category for a mandatory field in the link schema, but there are no default values available since we haven’t created any keywords.

Next, in a lower publication (040 Brand-Specific Content) we’ve created keywords for the category “URI Classification.”  By default, when you create a new component of type “link” the product (Tridion) automatically chooses the first value in the category as if it were a default value for that field.  However, it is not until you actually change the field value to something other than the first value (seemingly the default value to any normal person) that the value in the component gets populated..

When we then try to save the component it *thinks* that a mandatory field is left empty, and since the actual schema is defined as “minOccurs=1” it is throwing an xml validation error.

> XML validation error. Reason: The element 'Link' in namespace
>   'http://xxx.xxxxx.com/abc/site/Link' has invalid child element
>   'renderType' in namespace 'http://xxx.xxxxx.com/abc/site/Link'. List
>   of possible elements expected: 'uriClassification' in namespace
>   'http://xxx.xxxxx.com/abc/site/Link'.

Considering there are 4 content schema's in a schema-specific publication (e.g. 020 Schema Master).

When I attempt to go to my Content Publication, an create a new component, an XML error is triggered; which prevents successful save of a new component. I think its being displayed in these categories due to Tridion defaulting to a value that is not stored within the same publication as the category.

I am wondering if this is a product flaw, or a limitation depending on how you look at it. Its certainly not intuitive, regardless.

Has anyone else experienced this with `Categories` and `Keywords` before?

Comment: Our team encountered the same problem this week. The error message was saying that the field beneath was in the wrong order according to the schema - Which was correct, as the field above was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hotfix CME_2013.1.1.88649 is available for 2013 SP1 HR1, it resolved the same issue on my machine.

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/CME_2013.1.1.88649_tcm89-21615.zip

Answer (score 2):

**Quick Fix**: If you create a default keyword at the same level in the blueprint as that in which the schema and category live (020 Schema Master), and set the default value for the URIClassification field to be this value, the issue goes away.

Its a work-around, but it works for now..

Comment: I'll check with the team... But to me it _smells_ like a defect.

Comment: Ok. Ive opened a ticket with SDL support

Answer (score 1):

We had this same specific problem when using dropdowns for mandatory fields without a default value.

In the end, we decided just to manually update the 20 (configuration) components that used this schema.

Another alternative we discussed was changing the field type (from dropdown) to either radio buttons or the tree selector. However, this obviously depends on the structure and volume of your keywords.

However, this would just be a workaround. As Nuno says, this is possibly a glitch in the software (or browser), which hopefully will be fixed.